# Symfony Workflow Component Prolem... Marking Does not Exist

Tags: workflow, symfony

I am trying to learn how to use the Workflow Component

On this line in DefaultController.py (far below):

```
$service->apply($loginMessage, 'message_shown');
```

I get the message

```
Neither the property "marking" nor one of the methods "getMarking()", "marking()", "isMarking()", "hasMarking()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "UserFlowBundle\Entity\LoginMessage".
500 Internal Server Error - NoSuchPropertyException
```

What could be causing the error? My code is very similar to the [SFLive Example](https://github.com/lyrixx/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow), and I can't see what the difference is.

LoginModal.php

```
<?php

namespace UserFlowBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LoginMessage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="login_message")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserFlowBundle\Repository\LoginMessageRepository")
 */
class LoginMessage
{


    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->state = 'none';
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     *
     * @return LoginMessage
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param string $user
     *
     * @return LoginMessage
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

DefaultController.py

```
  <?php
    namespace UserFlowBundle\Controller;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    /**
     * @Route("/userflow")
     */
    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/")
         */
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
            return $this->render('UserFlowBundle:Default:index.html.twig', ['user'=>$user]);
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/apply-transition/", name="user_flow_apply_transition")
         * @Method("POST")
         */
        public function applyTransitionAction(Request $request)
        {
            try {
                $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
                $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
                $repository = $em->getRepository('UserFlowBundle:LoginMessage');
                $loginMessage = $repository->findOneOrCreateByUser($user);
                $service = $this->get('state_machine.loginModal');
                $service->apply($loginMessage, 'message_shown');
                #$service->apply($loginMessage, $request->request->get('transition'));
                $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->flush();
            } catch (ExceptionInterface $e) {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $e->getMessage());
            }
            return $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl('task_show', ['id' => 1])
            );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the workflow component, but I am quite familiar with symfony though.

After looking at https://github.com/lyrixx/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/Task.php, I recognized, you do not have declared the methods `getMarking` and `setMarking`, which is also what the error message says.

My educated guess is, that the workflow component needs some sort of marking which tells it, in which state the entity is.

Answer (score 3):

As states the Symfony doc:

> The type (default value single_state) and arguments (default value **marking**) attributes of the marking_store option are optional. If omitted, their **default values** will be used.

If the state property isn't named "marking", you can configure it as such:

```
# config/packages/workflow.yaml
framework:
workflows:
    my_workflow:
        type: 'state_machine'
        marking_store:
            type: 'single_state'
            arguments:
                - 'myStateProperty'
        support:
            - App\Entity\MyEntity
```

Comment: seems like if you pass only arguments key and miss type it doesn't read arguments value at all, good finding :+1

Comment: These days it's:
<framework:marking-store type="single_state">
         <framework:argument>yourEntity'sStateProperty</framework:argument>
</framework:marking-store>